# Were names of children often chosen as a reminder an essence or attribute of God?

Tags: names, children

Such examples might be Abel and Daniel. Such names would yield meaning and recall of Truth, such as Daniel's name meaning "God Judges" or for Abel's meaning "God breathes" or "God's breath" as these have the prefix El.

Comment: I thank those who make this site possible, shalom

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theophory_in_the_Bible

Comment: See also Rashi on 1 Shmuel 1:120: "Shmuel. After the Name of G-d [א־ל], and in reference to the incident he was so called, for I requested [שָׁאַל] him of הַשֵׁם[=מא־ל]."

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!